# How to get "nexepagelink" and "previoiuspagelink" in wp_link_pages?

Tags: pagination, navigation

I'm trying to get pagination in my pages, so I use this default option:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array(
    'before'           => '<div>',
    'after'            => '</div>',
    'link_before'      => '<span class="page-numbers">',
    'link_after'       => '</span>',
    'next_or_number'   => 'number',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page', 'behold-universal-one'),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page', 'behold-universal-one' ),
)); ?>
```

works all except "nextpagelink" and "previouspagelink". No matter what I use, no text next or previus pages is visible. Ofcourse there is more than one page break. Wordpress 5.1

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_link_pages()` doesn't support numbers *and* next/previous links. If you set `next_or_number` to `number`, the default, then the pages will be shown as number links. By default that looks like this:

```
Pages: 1 2 3
```

If you set it to `next` then you'll get this output:

```
Pages:Previous page Next page
```

The `nextpagelink` and `previouspagelink` arguments are used to changed those labels, but they won't add next and previous links to the numbered pagination.

Comment: I see.  I suggested archive pagination where except numbers I can get nav arrows before and after. So, in pages pagination via wp_link_pages can't do that, right?

Comment: Correct. The pagination used for archives does support this, but not pagination for page content.

Comment: Thanks, that's another time when your answer is clear and very usefull!